# Python 3 on Django 2 throws a UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: django, python-3.x, ubuntu

On my Django 2 / Python 3 project I get a UnicodeDecodeError when uploading an image to the server. Interestingly I don't get this error on my development PC. I only get this on the staging server.

models.py

```
from sorl.thumbnail import ImageField

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    ext_code = models.PositiveIntegerField("ext_code")
    avatar = ImageField(upload_to="avatars", default="", blank=True)
```

views.py

```
if request.method == "POST":
    image = request.FILES.get("avatar")
    user.avatar = image
    user.save()  # <-- Error is thrown here
```

my locale setup on the server

```
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

on manage.py shell I get this:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Oct  8 2019, 13:06:37)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.encoding
'UTF-8'
>>> import locale
>>> locale.getpreferredencoding(False)
'UTF-8'
```

And this is the error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf3' in position 75: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I also have included `# coding=utf-8` on all my python files.

My code seems to be OK, because the same image (filename is: `Vs_Filemón.png`) uploads fine on my development machine. So, I guess there must something broken on my staging machine which is this:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Comment: Sometimes this kind of error raises when you had a type for a field that has data in it, and then you decide to change it to another field type, is it your case?

Comment: I added my models on the description if that is what you ask for. I didn't change the type of the field.